# Is it possible to have multiple ingress paths under the same host that point to the same backend service

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, ingress

I'm trying to restrict access to certain paths on my service how can I accomplish this on kubernetes?
I have a service that runs a basic API but it also runs an admin service. Is it possible to use multiple paths under the same host as an ingress rule?

Example.com/API can be open but
Example.com/admin needs to be restricted. Both services run on the same backend service.

Comment: An ingress can certainly contain muliple path-based rules, but the question of "restricted" vs "not restricted" is really a decision that your application needs to make (e.g., by requiring authentication for the admin endpoints).